# How to Override bootstrap img height and width properties?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I use twitter bootstrap 2.3.2, there is this issue which is discussed in many places but still helpless. Bootstrap has specified

```
img {
  width : auto\9;
  height: auto;
}
```

When I render an image the height and width attributes of img tag are overridden by this css of bootstrap. I want to override this style unfortunately through css I am unable to do it. The problem is especially in IE as they have used IE specific style property.

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/fCMey/ 
The image looks smaller in chrome and firefox but in IE looks larger as in the original image size.

Other ways of fixing which I referred are 
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1899 - This is not working  I tried.
Similar SO issue
[How do I reset a twitter bootstrap reset to the browser's original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276137/how-do-i-reset-a-twitter-bootstrap-reset-to-the-browsers-original)

What I am looking for is I cannot set the height and width via inline style attribute as the image is added via third party editor. Also I use the bootstrap.css directly not the less file or any other way.

Are there any fix for this issue or I should directly remove the css from bootstrap.css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask...

> or I should directly remove the css from bootstrap.css

...to which in this case I would reply, "**Yes!**" Obviously, there is not going to be any more "updates" of bootstrap 2.3 now that they are into the 3+ release, so you will not need to worry about it being "overwritten" by an update.

Comment: Thank you. Have to go in with this option

Answer (score 1):

One to override bootstrap's css is to create your own custom css file and then include this file just below where you have included bootstrap.css.

Give the position property of the parent element of the img as relative and then apply `width:100%` or `height:100%` as desired to the img.

For example:
If your html is as below:

```
<div id="parentdiv">
   <img src="path/to/img.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Write the css inside your new custom css file as below:

```
#parentdiv{
    position: relative;
}

#position img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hopefully, this will resolve your problem.

You can also try adding, `!important` next to value of the width property (not recommended though).

```
width: 100% !important;
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for an alternative but this does not fix the issue when I tried with fiddle code plus I do not have control over the image tag and its parent as it is rendered via tiny mce editor.